# creating a slide show

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm working on a website for an animal rescue and I am trying to put an automatic slide show of a few of the animals up for adoption, however, for the life of me I cannot get the code to work. Any suggestions?

```
    <div class="photobanner" style="max-height:460px">
        <img class="myslides" src="image-1.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-2.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-3.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-4.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-5.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-6.jpg" style="height:100%" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me! What browser are you using? Is another script interfering with it?

Comment: Could you add some details about the exact problem you are facing? "cannot get the code to work" doesn't give enough information to the readers.

Comment: @Anurag I have the slide show in a div floated next to another div with overflow hidden, how ever when remove `overflow: hidden;` to see if that's the problem nothing happens. at this time i cannot see any of the photos nor a slide show

Comment: and im getting an of "uncaught typeerror cannot read property style of undefined pointing to `x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zaedmfLs/

```
var myIndex = 0;
setInterval(carousel, 2000);

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        console.log("Carousel");
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;

    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1} 
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

Few changes to your code:

1. Using setInterval instead of setTimeout
2. setInterval call to be made outside of carousel method as carousel needs to be invoked repeatedly.
3. There was a typo in `myslides` name (caps 'S')

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 major problems:

1. `mySlides` and `myslides` are not the same thing
2. instead of `setTimeout` I would use setInterval to call a function every 2 seconds

Here a suggestion

```js
var myIndex = 0;
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
setInterval(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

function carousel() {
    images[myIndex].style.display = "none";  

    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex >= images.length) {
      myIndex = 0;
    }
    console.log(myIndex, images.length);
    images[myIndex].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
img.myslides {
  display: None;
}
```

```html
    <div class="photobanner" style="max-height:460px">
        <img class="myslides" src="image-1.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-2.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-3.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-4.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-5.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="image-6.jpg" style="height:100%" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that i overlooked for the last hour or so and changing that my orig code works as well.